# Crashing Windows 7 using batch

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, windows-7, esxi

I came across this link : https://vmxp.wordpress.com/2014/10/29/stress-testing-an-esxi-host-with-windows-server-vms/
.Since I am not so good in powershell i turned the whole thing to a simple batch script:

```
:loop
start testlimit64 -d
timeout /t 15
taskkill /f /im "testlimit64.exe"
timeout /t 9
goto loop
```

Note that I got into SYSTEM ACCOUNT before doing that using PsExec. The system I am using is a VM under ESXi. But nothing is happening, even the vm is not crashing. My aim is to crash whole esxi server.
I have two VMs under the ESXi and I ran the above scripts in both of them.
Still no luck. Am I missing something?

Comment: Some thoughts: `cmd /C testlimit64 -d` instead of `start testlimit64 -d` and `taskkill /f /im "testlimit*"`

Comment: Perhaps **testlimit64.exe** cannot be found in any directory listed in environment variable **PATH** and is therefore not executed at all. Do you have tried calling **testlimit64.exe** with full path in double quotes if path contains a space character? Please note that environment variable **PATH** for system account contains definitely a different list of directories than **PATH** of your account.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2000 Feature Allows a Memory.dmp File to Be Generated with Keyboard

Q244139

---

The information in this article applies to:

Microsoft Windows 2000 Advanced Server 
Microsoft Windows 2000 Datacenter Server 
Microsoft Windows 2000 Professional 
Microsoft Windows 2000 Server

---

IMPORTANT: This article contains information about editing the registry. Before you edit the registry, make sure you understand how to restore it if a problem occurs. For information about how to do this, view the "Restoring the Registry" Help topic in Regedit.exe or the "Restoring a Registry Key" Help topic in Regedt32.exe.

SUMMARY
Microsoft Windows 2000 includes a feature that enables you to have the system stop responding and generate a Memory.dmp file (if configured to do so). The "Stop" screen that generates contains the following parameters:

*** STOP: 0x000000E2 (0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000,0x00000000)
The end-user manually generated the crashdump.

MORE INFORMATION
WARNING: Using Registry Editor incorrectly can cause serious problems that may require you to reinstall your operating system. Microsoft cannot guarantee that problems resulting from the incorrect use of Registry Editor can be solved. Use Registry Editor at your own risk.

For information about how to edit the registry, view the "Changing Keys and Values" Help topic in Registry Editor (Regedit.exe) or the "Add and Delete Information in the Registry" and "Edit Registry Data" Help topics in Regedt32.exe. Note that you should back up the registry before you edit it. If you are running Windows NT or Windows 2000, you should also update your Emergency Repair Disk (ERD).

This feature is disabled by default. To enable this feature, you must edit the registry as indicated below and restart the computer. After restarting the computer, you can generate a system to stop responding by holding down the right CTRL key and pressing the SCROLL LOCK key twice. Pressing left CTRL key does not generate the system to stop responding.

Please note that the steps below will not work on Legacy Free computers, i.e., those that use a USB keyboard. For those, you must attach a debugger.

Start Registry Editor (Regedt32.exe).

Locate the following key in the registry:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters 
On the Edit menu, click Add Value, and then add the following registry value:

Value Name: CrashOnCtrlScroll
Data Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1 
Quit Registry Editor.

Additional query words: blue screen force dump bluescreen crash memory.dmp

---

For USB keyboards a USB one was added in a later OS. This sets Left Ctrl + Space, Spece for both USB (kbdhid) and PS/2 (i8042) keyboards.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\crashdump]
"Dump1Keys"=dword:00000020
"Dump2Key"=dword:0000003D

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\crashdump]
"Dump1Keys"=dword:00000020
"Dump2Key"=dword:0000003D

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\i8042prt\Parameters]
"CrashOnCtrlScroll"=-

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\kbdhid\Parameters]
"CrashOnCtrlScroll"=-
```